# jlink not using automatic modules

Tags: java, jpackage

I created a '.exe' file for a JavaFX application on Windows 10 using jpackage. Afterward, by double-clicking on the application's icon, the app did not start. I realized that I mistakenly used this command, which is tailored for none modular application:

```
jpackage --input app-directory --main-jar jar-file [--main-class main-class]
```

Now I am trying to use the proper command syntax from Oracle doc for Modular application:

```
jpackage --module-path module-path --module main-module[/class]
```

Here is my command based on the syntax given by Oracle:

```
jpackage -p "%JAVAFX_HOME%\lib;%M2_REPO%;org\openjfx\mavenfxedittableview\mavenfxedittableview.jar" --module "org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview/org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview.TableEditApp"
```

However, I am getting an error regarding jlink not using automatic modules: The error message:

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.jpackage
jlink failed with: Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: javafx.swt from file:///C:/Program%20Files/java/jFX/javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1/lib/javafx-swt.jar
```

My application module name in the module-info.class is

```
module org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires java.base;
requires java.prefs;
requires transitive java.xml.bind;

opens org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview to java.xml.bind, javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview;
    
}
```

The application main is org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview.TableEditApp and the org\openjfx\mavenfxedittableview directory structure is a relative path within the "c:\sample" directory.

The build classes are:

```
 Directory of C:\Sample\org\openjfx\mavenfxedittableview

09/09/2020  10:32 PM    <DIR>          .
09/09/2020  10:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             2,502 addressBookData.xml
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             9,562 Address_Book.png
09/09/2020  08:36 PM               859 birthdaystatistic.fxml
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             3,274 BirthdaystatisticController.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             3,224 DarkTheme.css
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             2,072 DateUtil.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             1,214 LocalDateAdapter.class
09/09/2020  10:32 PM            34,004 mavenfxedittableview.jar
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             3,523 Person.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             4,535 personeditdialog.fxml
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             5,128 PersoneditdialogController.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             1,029 PersonListWrapper.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             6,412 personoverview.fxml
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             1,904 rootlayout.fxml
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             4,490 RootlayoutController.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             9,060 TableEditApp.class
09/09/2020  08:36 PM             6,812 TableVieweditController.class
              17 File(s)         99,604 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  56,574,193,664 bytes free
```

Here is the content of the application jar file:

```
     0 Wed Sep 09 22:32:14 IRDT 2020 META-INF/
   125 Wed Sep 09 22:32:14 IRDT 2020 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  2502 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/addressBookData.xml
  9562 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/Address_Book.png
   859 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/birthdaystatistic.fxml
  3274 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/BirthdaystatisticController.class
  3224 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/DarkTheme.css
  2072 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/DateUtil.class
  1214 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/LocalDateAdapter.class
  3523 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/Person.class
  4535 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/personeditdialog.fxml
  5128 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/PersoneditdialogController.class
  1029 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/PersonListWrapper.class
  6412 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/personoverview.fxml
  1904 Wed Sep 09 20:36:28 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/rootlayout.fxml
  4490 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/RootlayoutController.class
  9060 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/TableEditApp.class
  6812 Wed Sep 09 20:36:30 IRDT 2020 org/openjfx/mavenfxedittableview/TableVieweditController.class
   349 Wed Sep 09 22:32:14 IRDT 2020 module-info.class
```

This is the jar manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.openjfx.mavenfxedittableview.TableEditApp
Created-By: 14.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Finally, I found out about this Maven plugin ModiTect:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhuOSGrNBek
```

, which embeds a descriptor into the jar file of an automatic module, however that would be extremely tedious and time-consuming since the culprit automatic module is not even in my module descriptor. This implies that I might have to go through the .m2 repository and convert them one by one. Are there better work arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX It also uses jpackage and jlink but in a way that makes it usable for non-modular projects. You can't use jlink directly because it does not support automatic modules but this problem can be avoided by just not using the module system at all.

Comment: @minpa: Thank you for the tutorial. I followed the steps in the tutorial, modify my own pom, and retrofitted the command line script to create a ".exe" file for the application. I run the ".exe" file and installed the app on my Windows 10 but I observered the same symptom as described in my post, which is double-clicking on the application icon, does not start the application. I have managed to run the application from the command line using the main class and also using the AppLauncher technique that was introduced by the tutorial. Do I need to create an MSI image rather than the ".exe"?

Comment: By the way,  I created a ".exe" for the tutorial, installed it on my system, and I was able to start the app by double-clicking on the icon. However, my app is a little bit more contrived, using several dialog windows, and uses JAXB to store data on the file system. However, as I indicated, I was able to run the application using the app jar file and also via the AppLauncher from the command line.

Comment: To get the real user experience on windows I'd reccomend to create an MSI installer. At least that is what I am doing. After installation the app can be used like any other app on the system.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the MSI installer, it's much faster and more efficient, despite the installer type, alas the problem persists. I have a hunch that jpackage or the jlink are not including some libs or artifacts with bundle. Time to put some logs into the AppLauncher and the main class.

Comment: Interestingly, no exceptions or errors being reported in the log. This is a tough one to beat and it will remain a mystery :-), oh well, thanks for the tutorial, it certainly circumnavigates the limitation of jlink in regards to automatic modules.

Comment: I MUST admit that user error certainly influences the end result. I've removed the AppLauncher from the build script inadvertently and that's why the application would not start when double-clicking its icon :-). THANK YOU!!

Comment: I am glad it finally works. Building installers instead of fat jars is the future.